# Find words from the array in the text received through file_get_contents

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have a receipt of a remote page:

```
$page = file_get_contents ('http://sayt.ru/');
```

There is a array of words:

```
$word = array ("word", "second");
```

How to count the number of words in the array matches the text on the page?
Started to dig in the direction

```
$matches = array ();
$count_words = preg_match_all ('/'. $word. '/ i',$page, $matches);
```

But certainly not in the direction I dig because count is always zero. And through preg_match_all sought after one word, not the entire array. : (

Answer (score 3):

you have to either check or each word in array or use regexp like this:

```
$serachWords = array_map(function($w){ return preg_quote($w,'/'); }, $word);
$search = implode('|', $searchWords);
$count_words = preg_match_all('/\b(?:'.$serach.')\b/i', $page, $matches);
```

Added few modification to have better results: escape all words, so they wouldn't break expression and add word boundaries (`\b`) no match `word` as a word, not part of `swords`.

Comment: I added to modifications to have more accurate results